# Is there a centralised website for bus travel in Brazil?

Tags: online-resources, buses, brazil

In Argentina, for example, [plataforma10](http://www.plataforma10.com/) was generally the go-to website for travellers for bus companies - while it didn't do every company, it had most of the big ones, and to all destinations in Argentina (and some neighbouring cities).

I'm wondering if there's a similar resource for bus travel in Brazil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one and only country-wide official source is the [website of the Agencia Nacional de Transportes Terrestres (ANTT)](http://www.antt.gov.br/), the Brazilian’s government official body for road transportation. Apparently its an unfriendly website to get to grips with.

This blog entitled **"[Brazil Travel Blog - 7 years travelling throughout Brazil](http://www.braziltravelblog.com/2008/11/29/bus-transportation-in-brazil/)"**  provides additional resources for the ANTT (inc. a step by step guide to using the ANTT site) & other sites relating to bus travel within Brazil:

Comment: I usually wait a while to see if there are other answers, and go through questions in bulk accepting every so often.  But since you asked, I'll do so now.

Comment: @MarkMayo Mark thats fine (I agree with you actually), but I thought because the ANTT is the only source and no one else answered plus the blog is informative (thats the only reason I asked)

Answer (score 5):

When I was in Brazil, I used [Busca Onibus](http://www.buscaonibus.com.br/en/) website. It lists times, company, price and class (type) of bus. However, not all bus companies are included.

Answer (score 3):

We recently added a lot of routes from Brazil here at [Busbud](http://www.busbud.com). You can travel across Brazil by booking bus tickets via our platform. You can compare companies, prices and schedules, some of these trips are very long, 50 hours for Sao Paulo - Fortaleza! The Brazilian Gringo will give you more tips about travelling by bus in Brazil on his blog.

You can browse the information in your language and book in your currency, no need to hold local currency or a CPF number, a regular passport is fine.

If you are in Brazil for the World Cup, we launched the [Brazil Bus Finder](http://www.busbud.com/en/world-cup) for football fans to get in time to the games!

Comment: I'm still upset that I'd spent a considerable amount of time on a bus route website, and then discovered Busbud and immediately folded :) Great work guys!